# Remove Spinner Padding between text and icon

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I want to remove padding between text and icon,
iattach image below

[image]

This is layout code

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bt_close"
            android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:layout_width="?actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:tint="@color/grey_60"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_chevron_left"/>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:id="@+id/directory_list"
            />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:layout_width="?actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:tint="@color/grey_60"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_done"
            android:id="@+id/done"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

i can't figure out

P.S
I search in stackoverflow about this but no one working, so i decided to ask a question here,
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

- Change the hard-coded value of the Spinner width to `wrap_content`
- add the below theme to the spinner

So, your spinner :

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/directory_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

Comment: its not working i tried wrap_content , its giving larger than previous

Comment: @HameedR I just updated the answer .. try to add this theme